# How can I get more information about the Voronoi integral in Gaussian09?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am working on metal based organic complexes to find out catalytic characters. I am using the B3LYP density functional level of theory in Gaussian09.
I need to know the possible keywords for getting effects of Voronoi integral where I use the keyword `EmpiricalDispersion = GD3`. This is not a cluster, but the central metal atom is $\ce{Fe}$. How can I obtain more output about it?

Comment: cross-post: http://www.chemicalforums.com/index.php?topic=92398.0

Comment: I know quite a bit about the D3 correction, but have never heard of a Voronoi integral being involved in that. Note that the Grimme corrections do not affect the electron density/KS-determinant (beyond the change in geometry if they were used in obtaining coordinates).

Comment: Thank You Martin and TAR86 for giving concentration on my topic. During study I obtained some distorted results. Someone suggested to apply Voronoi Integral, but I couldn't find any information about it in Gaussian Reference book and in available network search. But one thing I know that for more accurate transition states or structure conversion we can include 'int=fine' or 'int=ultrafine' in ipput line. But not sure that it is the same as that of Voronoi integral. That is why I just expect suggestion from the experts. Is there any other keywords that can convert in more accurate structure?

Comment: The only thing I was able to find is the VDD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_deformation_density - which either is or is not implemented in the QC code of your choice. The int= choices you mention are most likely unrelated to the VDD, this is a different integration altogether. As for accuracy of structures and methods for that, I have to refer you to the literature. We cannot reasonably be expected to tell you which is the best method without more details (and even then, it will be nigh impossible).

Comment: These things are completely unrelated to each other. Voronoi population analysis is a real-space partitioning of the electron density, where the boundary lines are given by Voronoi cells. It has nothing to do with empirical dispersion corrections. It is also only available in [ADF](https://www.scm.com/doc/ADF/Input/Results_Output.html#hirshfeld-charges-voronoi-deformation-density).

Comment: By introducing the following keywords in inputline produces the relative better results. "EmpiricalDispersion=GD3 Int=ultrafine"